# loop over multiple dataframes and saving multiple lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a bunch of dataframes, like the ones below:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['1', '2', 'mary', 123], ['1', '3', 'john', 234 ], ['2', '4', 'layla', 345 ]]
data2 = [['2', '6', 'josh', 345], ['1', '2', 'dolores', 987], ['1', '4', 'kate', 843]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['state', 'city', 'name', 'number1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['state', 'city', 'name', 'number1'])
```

for some silly reason I need to transform it in a list in this manner (for each row):

```
list(
    df1.apply(
        lambda x: {
            "profile": {"state": x["state"], "city": x["city"], "name": x["name"]},
            "number1": x["number1"],
        },
        axis=1,
    )
)
```

what returns me exactly what I need:

```
[{'profile': {'state': '1', 'city': '2', 'name': 'mary'}, 'number1': 123},
 {'profile': {'state': '1', 'city': '3', 'name': 'john'}, 'number1': 234},
 {'profile': {'state': '2', 'city': '4', 'name': 'layla'}, 'number1': 345}]
```

It works if I do it for each dataframe, but I need to write a function so I can use it latter. Also, I need to be able to store both df1 and df2 separately after the operation.

I tried something like this:

```
df_list = [df1, df2]
for row in df_list:
    row = list(row.apply(lambda x: {'send': {'state':x['state'], 'city':x['city'], 'name':x['name']}, 'number1':x['number1']}, axis=1))
```

but it saves only the value of the last df in the list (df2) row.

also, I tried something like this (and a lot of other stuff):

```
new_values = []
for row in df_list:
    row = list(row.apply(lambda x: {'send'{'state':x['state'],'city':x['city'],'name':x['name']},'number1':x['number1']}, axis=1))
    new_values.append(df_list)
```

I know it might be about not been saving the row value locally. I've read a lot posts here similar to my problem, but I couldn't manage to fully use then... Any help will be appreciated, I'm really stuck here..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
def func(df):
    return list(df.apply(lambda x:{'profile' : {'state': x['state'],'city': x['city'],'name':x['name']},'number1': x['number1']}, axis=1))
```

you can use it just like that:

```
df1 = func(df1)
```

also if you want to map all of data frames:

```
df1, df2 = [func(df) for df in [df1, df2]]
```

Comment: Hey, it worked perfectly!!! Thanks a lot for your help!!!, I was really stuck!!!